# Difference between `Stream.each/2` and `Stream.map/2`?

Tags: elixir

They have the same (or equivalent) typespecs:

```
each(Enumerable.t(), (element() -> term())) :: Enumerable.t()
```

```
map(Enumerable.t(), (element() -> any())) :: Enumerable.t()
```

The types `term` and `any` are equivalent per the docs:

- [Built-in types – Typespecs — Elixir v1.13.4](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/typespecs.html#built-in-types)

The docs don't point out any obvious differences, beyond the intended/expected usage (`each/2` mentions side effects):

- [`each/2` – Stream — Elixir v1.12.3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Stream.html#each/2)
- [`map/2` – Stream — Elixir v1.12.3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Stream.html#map/2)

For simple examples they seem equivalent:

```
iex(5)> Stream.each( [1, 2, 3], &(&1) ) |> Enum.to_list()
[1, 2, 3]
iex(8)> Stream.map( [1, 2, 3], &(&1) ) |> Enum.to_list() 
[1, 2, 3]
```

The example in the docs for `each/2` also seems to work fine with `map/2`:

```
iex(9)> stream = Stream.map([1, 2, 3], fn x -> send(self(), x) end)
#Stream<[enum: [1, 2, 3], funs: [#Function<48.50989570/1 in Stream.map/2>]]>
iex(10)> Enum.to_list(stream)
[1, 2, 3]
iex(11)> receive do: (x when is_integer(x) -> x)
1
iex(12)> receive do: (x when is_integer(x) -> x)
2
iex(13)> receive do: (x when is_integer(x) -> x)
3
```

If `Stream.each/2` and `Stream.map/2` ARE different – which I'm *guessing* they are – what is a simple example demonstrating those differences (that could be easily run in `iex`)? Do they differ in less obvious (e.g. harder to demonstrate) ways as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Stream.map/2` will *transform* the enumerable: it RETURNS the result of its operation.  `Stream.each/2` does not modify the enumerable; it's useful for emitting side-effects only.

```
iex> Stream.map([1, 2, 3], fn x -> x * 2 end) |> Enum.to_list()
[2, 4, 6]
iex> Stream.each([1, 2, 3], fn x -> x * 2 end) |> Enum.to_list()
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I read the other answer first, noticed that he implied this, and was about to write basically what you wrote – thanks!

Comment: I think part of why I was confused is because `Enum.each/2` returns `:ok` (which now seems weird) and the docs for `Stream.each/2` don't include any info about its return value beyond the typespec.

Comment: @KennyEvitt `Enum.each/2` is a terminating operation - you run the function on each element for its side effect and you're done, hence `:ok`, but `Stream.each/2` is not terminating, the stream is left untouched for further operations.

Comment: The wording in “it RETURNS the result”‍is not quite correct. It rather “passes through each element,” because the main difference between `Stream` and `Enum` is the former is lazy, and the latter is eager. Returning itself from `Enum.each/2` would require a whole copy of the enumerable in memory, which might be quite inefficient. `Stream.each/2` is free from this issue, hence passing elements through is a good option.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip I'm not sure what "terminating operation" means _exactly_ or where that terminology comes from, but I think I agree that `Enum.each/2` is what you claim. I just didn't know that _before_! The comment after yours includes some good info about _why_ the two functions behave differently.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Your comment makes a lot of sense. I, at first, was wondering why it'd be a problem for `Enum.each/2` to create a 'copy' of the original enumerable, but then I realized that I was 'anchored' on, e.g. lists, as an 'enumerable' instead of realizing that lots of other 'structures' can be used with `Enum`, including lazy ones.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Is there any value/purpose in using `Enum.each/2` versus `Stream.each/2`? Obviously one reason to use the latter would be to 'preserve' the original enumerable. But what advantage is there to using the former? I guess it would be more clearly what Adam described as a "terminating operation", but are there any other reasons? Maybe because `Enum.each/2` is more concise than `enum |> Stream.each(&blah/1) |> Stream.run()` (or different somehow)?

Comment: `Stream` is a lazy enumerator, it walks and passes through the enumerable element by element. `Enum` functions are greedy. Compare `[1,2] |> Enum.map(&IO.inspect/1) |> Enum.each(&IO.inspect/1)` vs `[1,2] |> Stream.each(&IO.puts/1) |> Stream.each(&IO.puts/1) |> Stream.run()` to see the difference.

Answer (score 3):

> what is a simple example demonstrating those differences (that could be easily run in iex)?

Here's a stream that squares a number then converts to strings:

```elixir
iex> 1..10 |> Stream.map(&(&1*&1)) |> Stream.map(&Integer.to_string/1) |> Enum.to_list()
["1", "4", "9", "16", "25", "36", "49", "64", "81", "100"]
```

You can see that the transformed output of the first map was used in the 2nd map.

If we however switch either of those `map`s to `each`, the stream is not transformed and the stream retains its previous output:

Not squared, but converted to strings:

```elixir
iex> 1..10 |> Stream.each(&(&1*&1)) |> Stream.map(&Integer.to_string/1) |> Enum.to_list()
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
```

Squared, but not converted to string:

```elixir
iex> 1..10 |> Stream.map(&(&1*&1)) |> Stream.each(&Integer.to_string/1) |> Enum.to_list()
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

> Do they differ in less obvious (e.g. harder to demonstrate) ways as well?

No, but using `each` without generating a side-effect is not the intended use-case. The real benefit of `each` is to do things like inspect the current value between stages:

```elixir
iex> inspect_even = fn x -> IO.puts("#{x} is #{if rem(x, 2) == 0, do: "even", else: "odd"}") end
iex> 1..3 |> Stream.each(inspect_even) |> Stream.map(&(&1 * 2)) |> Stream.each(inspect_even) |> Enum.to_list
1 is odd
2 is even
2 is even
4 is even
3 is odd
6 is even
[2, 4, 6]
```